# Upload a list of customers email to Google Ads Management API

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to upload a list of customers hashed email using [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData#examples) guide, and here's my code.

```
File file = new File("/customerMatchHashed.csv");
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream",
    new FileInputStream(file));
mediaContent.setLength(file.length());

try {
  Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
  analytics.management().uploads().uploadData("AccountIdHere",
      "UA-123456-1", "1223334444", mediaContent).execute();
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
  System.err.println("There was a service error: "
      +  e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
      +  e.getDetails().getMessage());
}
```

I keep on running into this error.

> There was a service error: 400 : Invalid custom data source ID format: xxxxx.

The error is self explanatory, but I don't know where to get this `custom data source ID` from (it is supposed to be a string), as I don't see any such thing in the Google Analytics console. Similarly, the `web property Id`, is also a string, but I don't see it in the console. 
I would appreciate any help/guidance in where to get these two properties from.

Comment: i think you should do a [list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources/list) to get back the correct id.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, it still needs the webPropertyId. CustomDataSources sources = analytics.management().
          customDataSources().list("accountId", "webPropertyId").execute();

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "message" : "Invalid client data: Invalid argument: Property not found <tracking id:account_id: accountId\nlog_number: 1\n>."
}

Comment: Then your account and web properties ids are wrong do a  [accountSummaries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) and find the account id and web proeprty id that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is a [accountSummaries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list).  This will give you a list of all the accounts that the currently authenticated user has access to.

```
AccountSummaries accountSummaries = service.management().accountSummaries().list().execute();
```

Then once you have found the account with the web property where you have set up the [data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) in the google analytics admin section. You can run a [custom data sources list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources/list) which will return all of the custom data sources set up for that account.

```
CustomDataSources sources = analytics.management().customDataSources().list(AccountIdFromPreviousRequest, WebpropertyIdFromPreviousReqeust).execute();
```

You can then use the id returned in your upload

```
analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(AccountIdFromFirstRequest,
                                            WebpropertyIdFromFirstReqeust,                                                
                                           customDataSourcesFromPrevousRequest,
                                           mediaContent).execute();
```

Comment: better than never, thanks for taking the time out. I ended up reading data from Big Query and this issue wasn't re produced there.